# Maven application missing runtime jars

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a maven app that requires external jars. I am able to build my app fine. When I deploy to Tomcat (via IntelliJ), and run my app, I am getting many NoClassDefFound errors. To get past this issue, I am having to copy the missing jars from my .m2 folder to my Tomcat lib directory.

When I check my exploded war in the deployable app, the WEB-INF/lib directory doesn't have the missing jars. So obviously my app will complain.

My question is, how do I get my maven to include runtime jars in the deployable war file? The thing is, I have other people working on the same app, using the same POM, and no one needs to copy the missing jars to Tomcat.

```
            <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope> 
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Share the pom file or fragment please

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik It's quite large. Can you be more specific about the parts you'd like to check? I can paste those.

Comment: I am getting the exact problem. Other Maven projects work fine. Nothing suggested here works, except for adding the jars to the tomcat/lib directory. All my dependencies are in default (compile) scope which should make them available at runtime. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the missing jars into my Tomcat libs dir and Tomcat was able to find them. It's not the right way to do this but it let me out in the short term. I need to fix the POM long term.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this issue in the future :

I had exactly the same issue - jars in the pom weren't available at runtime, neither were jars in the Java Build Path. The only workaround I could find was to add the jars to the tomcat/lib directory.

Turns out my Maven local repository was corrupt - I don't know how much of it was, but at least some of it was. I renamed the .m2/repository directory to oldrepository, attempted a "clean install" again (took a while for all the jars to download again) and everything worked perfect after that.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have dependencies declared with a `<scope>provided</scope>`, or maybe they are by accident in a `test`-scope. Maven will not package these dependencies in your warfile.

If they are not classical dependencies but *real* external jars added to the classpath in another way, ie out of Mavens reach, you might want to install them to your local repository via `mvn install:install-file` to get them properly recognized by Maven.

If you cannot install the jar to your local repository for any reason, another option might be the `system` scope where you give the exact location of said jar, but this would not pack the jar into the warfile either, instead, you would have to make sure that said jar is located in said location on the server.

Since other people do not seem to have the problem (which would be weird), check if you have any local modifications, and recheck their warfiles. If you can compile all right, but the warfile is not the same file the others get, there must be something off on your side.

More on scopes [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Answer (score 0):

Use scope "runtime" instead of "provided".

From maven documentation:

"runtime- this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath".

So in your case it should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: I get this error: jaxb\services\XmlHolder.java:19: package org.apache.xml.serialize does not exist. This is because the app needs to jar at compile as well as runtime.

Comment: Using compile scope adds the jar to my deployed jar but I still get a 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/serialize/OutputFormat' error when I run the app.

Comment: If others have their scope as provided, and their apps are running, then I'm not sure changing the POM is what is required. In saying that, they could have hacked their config.

Comment: It seems that you and others has own instance of Tomcat. Others has missing jars in a classpath of a Tomcat instance, either in Tomcat's lib deirectory or in a java classpath that starts Tomcat instance. So, you shoul put missing libs in these places. Or use runtime scope as I stated.